# Lost/disappeared shape_length an shape_area fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, shape-area

I have a vast database which includes a shape length and shape area field. One day, after doing some fc to fc layers from said feature class, I opened the attribute table and the shape length and shape area fields had disappeared completely! I have no idea where they've gone.

Any ideas what's happened?

I'm new to GIS so don't know how to manually calculate them and put them back in.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Is the "feature class" that you have lost these fields from a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class?

Comment: Import the feature class into a file or personal geodatabase, this will add and calculate the shape_length (perimeter) and shape_area fields **in their current coordinate system**, these fields are read-only and should stay with the feature class when you export to a shapefile. If you want to calculate length/area in a coordinate system other than the one that the data is in you can use Calculate Field with an advanced calculation projecting use projectAs - more information is needed for this calculation but I am hesitant to confuse the subject unless this is *really* needed.

Comment: @PolyGeo, they're from a shapefile...

Comment: If your data is a shapefile then add the fields using Add Fields, then calculate the fields using Field Calculator. But if you export the shapefile to a file geodatabase you will get the fields automatically and they will also be updated if you modify the features. In shapefile format you will have to recalculate them after every edit.